# Apache redirect multiple https domains to one https domain using virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, https, redirect

I’m running a CentOS Server with apache 2.4 that serves two domains: `myurl.domain.com` and `myurl.otherdomain.com`. Using virtualhosts I want all requests to be redirected to `https://myurl.domain.com`. 
What works: people who visit `http://myurl.domain.com` and `http://myurl.otherdomain.com` are redirected to `https://myurl.domain.com/`. 
What does not work: redirecting `https://myurl.otherdomain.com` to `https://myurl.domain.com/`.

See my httpd config here:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
       # this part does not seem to work...
       SSLEngine on
       ServerName myurl.otherdomain.com
       ServerAlias www.myurl.otherdomain.de
       Redirect / https://myurl.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/CA/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/CA/new.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/CA/chain.pem
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        TimeOut 600
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName myurl.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.myurl.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName myurl.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.myurl.domain.com myurl.otherdomain.com www.myurl.otherdomain.de
        TimeOut 600
        Redirect / https://myurl.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `SSLCertificateFile`, `SSLCertificateKeyFile` and `SSLCertificateChainFile` directives to the 443 virtual host for `myurl.otherdomain.com` too, even if it's only redirecting to your main domain. Make sure that you use a SSL certificate that is valid for this domain. After that restart the apache service.